# Is converting to String the most succinct way to remove the last comma in output in java?

Tags: java

So basically this is how my code looked like

```
public static void printPrime(int[] arr)
    {
        int len = arr.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            int c = countFactor(arr[i]);

            if(c == 2)
            {
             System.out.print(arr[i] + ",");
            }

        }
    }
```

So the output did have the 'comma' in the end. I tried looking around to remove the last comma some answers say to print last element separately but that can only happen when output depends on the for loop  and not the if condition. 
But as you can see I don't know how many elements I am going to get from the *if condition*. Only two things I can think of, to add another loop or use String then substr to output.

So I converted it to String

```
public static void printPrime(int[] arr)
    {
        int len = arr.length;
        String str = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            int c = countFactor(arr[i]);

            if(c == 2)
            {
              str = str + arr[i] + ",";
            }

        }
        str = str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

My question is about knowing  the optimum way (converting to string then substringing it?) for similar questions or could there be a better way as well? That I seem to be missing.

Comment: you can use `String.join`

Comment: Yup. Collect the values from `countFactor()` somewhere and then use `String.join()` on them. For extra credit use `IntStream` to stream the array so you don't need to create extra space for the values of `countFactor()`.

Comment: @Shad it is not a good idea to use string concatenation in a loop: if you're going to build a string, use a `StringBuilder` to avoid constructing lots of intermediate strings.

Comment: @Kayaman I am not actually directly using values from the `countFactor()` and outputting them.
I am operating on integer array elements as you can see.

Comment: @Kayaman And since I should be using String.join() first of all, I suppose I should be converting all int elements from the array into String.Adding to Single String won't do because all elements added to that string would make it one element string. String array won't do since I don't know the size before hand. So I suppose I am left with using String ArrayList? 
And then finally use String.join on it.

Comment: Yeah something like that, `List<Integer>` would work jus fine too.

Comment: huh? But String.join() does not permit using `List<Integer>`!

Comment: Ah, what a shame. I guess they wanted to avoid accidents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to construct a string. Consider the following slight tweaks:

```
public static void printPrime(int[] arr)
{
    int len = arr.length;
    String sep = "";    // HERE
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        int c = countFactor(arr[i]);

        if(c == 2)
        {
         System.out.print(sep);  // HERE
         sep = ",";
         System.out.print(arr[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Print the delimiter first, and store its value in a variable: the first time it's printed, it will print the empty string. Thereafter, it prints the comma.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever means you use should operate correctly for an empty array (length 0), a singleton array (length 1) and a long array (a large length).

Adding the comma then removing it requires special case handling for the empty array case. So you must have conditional code (an if statement) whatever you do.

Comment: @AndyTurner's answer does without an extra conditional.